# Dialog.Show Args

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Does anybody know what the args are in the VSTO Excel dialog.show function?

i.e. I would like to set the Sort Option to select "Header Row" but have no idea how to do this as I can only get the function working by passing missing in for every arg.

```
Globals.RiskViewerWorkbook.ThisApplication.Dialogs[XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogSort].Show(missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2003 at least, for `xlDialogSort` the args are as follows (starting with `Arg1`):

```
orientation, key1, order1, key2, order2, key3, order3, header, custom, case
```

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221648%28office.11%29.aspx) for a list of all of the arguments for built-in dialogs